# Navigation Controller within the ViewController - iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

As you see in the image below, I implemented navigation controller to go back and forward.
That works fine.

My question is how to implement another navigation controller in the page for tableViewController. Whenever user clicks on any column, it will take him to detail information of selected column.

I would like to know how you could implement navigation controller in the page.

[image]

Comment: have you looked into `UISplitViewController` ? 
Sample Tutorial: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-landscape.html and

Comment: I know, but I dont want to work with UISPlitViewController

Answer (score 0):

UISplitViewController seems like the best solution to what you're going for, but since you stated you don't want to use it, lets get to the direct question.
There is nothing to stop you from programmatically creating a UINavigationController, initiating it with some view controller, and adding said UINavigationController as a subview of the current view controller.

As such, you'd have your primary NavigationController, which on the given view has a view controller containing a table view on the left, and a map view on the right.  When a user clicks an appropriate table entry, you add the navigation controller to the current view controller, sized/positioned however you want (say, below the map, or maybe over the map, hiding it completely?).  When the user wishes to remove the navigation controller (clicking another table entry maybe?), simply remove the navigation controller subview.

You'd probably need to add said navigation controller as a childViewController to allow it to get all the neat rotation function calls and stuff.  I actually have defines which add a view as a childViewController and subview, and then remove it as necessary.  Of course, this is assuming you have a view to which you are adding the navigation controller; and you want the navigation controller to take up the entire view (so size the view appropriately)

```
#define addChildViewController(childController, parent) { \
    [self addChildViewController:childController]; \
    childController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,parent.frame.size.width,parent.frame.size.height); \
    [parent addSubview:childController.view]; \
    [childController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; \
}

#define removeChildViewController(child) { \
    [child willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; \
    [child.view removeFromSuperview]; \
    [child removeFromParentViewController]; \
}
```